# how to handle Instagram access token expired error

Tags: objective-c, instagram, access-token, instagram-api

I have an Instagram api used app 
while I am accessing user medias I am getting this response I do not  know how to handle this error. I am using this api

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=accesstoken

```
     code = 400;
    "error_message" = "The access_token provided is invalid.";
    "error_type" = OAuthAccessTokenException;
```

Comment: The access_token provided is invalid. Did you check your access_token?

Answer (score 2):

I think may be your access token is invalid so you need to re-authenticate the user to get new access token .Try With that new token it  will work for you.